# Create a dialog prompt for user to select sim for call in dual sim

Tags: android, phone-call, sim-card, dual-sim

I want a user to select from which sim card is a call is to be made when he clicks a on call.

The call function is below, how do i implement this. Heard Dual Sim support is available for android

```
 public void Call(String tel)
    {
        String Hash = Uri.encode("#");
        int permissionCheck= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
        if (permissionCheck!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},123);
            //requestPhonePermission();
        }else
        {

            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"*"+141+"*"+tel+Hash));            
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //TODO prompt for sim to call from
            intent.putExtra("com.android.phone.force.slot", true);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: no still looking for a solution